# hgignore multi line regex

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I googled a bit, but didn't find any suggestions on that topic. Is multi line regex possible in .hgignore?
I'm writing a magento module, and wan't to include only my module code in repository, so I came up with this regex, but it would a be mess, if I had to write it in one line.

```
syntax: regexp
^(?!(
   app/code/local/Mage/Myreviews/|
   app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/myreviews\.xml|
   app/design/frontend/default/default/template/myreviews/|
   app/etc/modules/Mage_Myreviews\.xml|
   skin/frontend/default/default/css/myreviews/|
   skin/frontend/default/default/myreviews/|
   js/myreviews/
)).*
```

Comment: Hm, kind of a `.hginclude`... I don't think that there is a better way than to do the single-line regex.

Comment: @Lucero what is `.hginclude`? Is it a standard part of mercurial or a module?

Comment: it's just a name I made up for what you want to do. By default Mercurial is "opt-out" - it needs to be told what to ignore. What you want is to use it in an opt-in way, e.g. tell it what to include. I'm not aware of such functionality.

Comment: A `.hginclude` file has been discussed once in a while on the mailing lists and issue tracker, but not implemented. Only tracking a small subset is an uncommon situation, and it is actually safer to take the approach in jk's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the canonical answer to your question, are multi-line regular expressions supported? No. For confirmation, take a look at the `ignorepats` function in `ignore.py` in the `mercurial` Python package—it iterates over the lines in the file one by one.

As for what you should do instead, @jk.'s answer is good (and the `glob: *` that you've come up with).

Answer (score 3):

You can add files to a repository and have mercurial track them even if they match an ignore rule, so usually the best way to do this sort of thing is to ignore a bit too much e.g. (don't know anything about magneto modules so this may be wrong)

```
syntax: glob
app/*
skin/*
js/myreviews/*
```

and then explicitly [hg add](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#commands) the files you do want.

As Joel points out `hg add`s `--include` and `--exclude` options are also useful in these scenarios

pre-emptive additional info: `hg forget` will undo tracking a file without deleting it

Comment: +1: And before you think you'll have to add each individually, `hg add` has `--include` and `--exclude` that accept patterns. Use `--dry-run` to test them (shows you what it would add with those patterns).

Comment: maybe then `syntax: glob *` ?

Comment: sure you could do that, it would mean ignore everything unless i explicitly tell you to track something

Comment: This solution has a big drawback. If I will create a new file in directory I added previously, it won't appear in `hg status`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: you can see them with hg status -i, but then you'll get all ignored files

Comment: Another drawback is I can't add whole folders eg. `hg add app/code/` with `glob: *`. I have to remove it first, add folders, and put it back... I like regex solution better, but can't make it work. It works fine in regexbuddy(regex editor), but doesn't work in `.hgignore`. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: I suspect the best you will get will be to use mutliple glob or regexp patterns as tight as possible and then add in enything which you actually need but matches a pattern